# Assigning pointer in Objective C or C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

```
NSHost *instance = [NSHost currentHost];
NSString *answer = [instance localizedName];
NSLog(@"%@",answer);
```

Ok, I know the basics of pointer but I have some doubts on this 3 line of code. After posting a similar question on this website, still the answer i got doesn't really answer my question.
So, first of all,
I know that pointer needs to hold an address.
But why don't we do something like this?
    NSHost*instance=&[NSHost currentHost];
adding &. This is because only & shows the address of something.

2nd question what does 
    [NSHost currentHost]
return

does it return address of its instance?
IF not how can we assign NSHost*instance=[NSHost currentHost]; its wrong.

third question,
I know that NSString *answer = [instance localizedName]; returns an instane of NSString because its written in a book and I'm using it now to complete the challenge in the book.
in this code  NSString *answer = [instance localizedName]
are we assigning a pointer to a pointer?? because [instance localizedName] returns a pointer of NSString.

Comment: When it comes to objects, there is no such thing as an object type in Objective-C, only Objective-C pointers. In other words, you never assign objects, you always assign pointers to objects.

Comment: @Jano - I think what you mean to say is that there is no such thing as a *variable* which is of an object type.  Obviously, there are objects and they have types (classes), but you never actually assign (copy) the object, only its pointer.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, much better explained, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You don't add a `&`, because `currentHost` already returns a pointer. Check out its header:

   ```
   + (NSHost *)currentHost
   ```

   It returns an `NSHost*` and you assign it to an `NSHost*`.
2. `[NSHost currentHost]` will return a pointer to a specific instance of NSHost.
3. Same thing here. localizedName returns a pointer to an `NSString` (`NSString*`) and you assign it to one.

Comment: Hi, so are we assigning a pointer to a pointer with this code                NSHost *instance = [NSHost currentHost];

Answer (score 14):

When teaching Objective-C classes, I use this analogy to explain the (somewhat confusing) concept of pointers:

1) When you create an uninitialized variable, like `int val;`, it creates a "bucket" that can hold an integer **value**. The bucket itself has a **memory address**.

[image]

2) When you **assign** a value to the variable with `val = 5;`, you put that value into the bucket:

[image]

3) A **pointer variable** (one with a leading asterisk `*`) like `int *ptr;` is a "bucket", that does not contain a **value**, but the **memory address** of another "bucket":

[image]

4) To a pointer variable you assign **not the value** that is contained in another bucket, but the **memory address** of that other bucket. You get the "bucket address" of a value's bucket by putting the `&` (ampersand) character in front of the variable name:

[image]

That being said, when a method already returns a **pointer variable** (like `NSString *`), you already get the memory address and don't have to ask for it again by using `&`.

To bring the point home, in this example, we have 2 buckets:

```
NSString *text = @"Test";
```

The first bucket contains the **value** (@"Test"), the second bucket contains the **memory address** of the first bucket. Or, to use the bucket analogy again: `@"Test"` is in the left bucket, and the right bucket (the variable `text`) contains the memory address of the left bucket. We can see that by running this:

```
NSLog(@"value: %@, bucket that contains value: %p, bucket that contains the memory address of the bucket containing the value: %p", text, text, &text);
// output: value: Test, bucket that contains value: 0x1032f5030, bucket that contains the memory address of the bucket containing the value: 0x7fff5c90bb68
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** & **2)**

`NSHost *instance = [NSHost currentHost];` returns a pointer of `NSHost` object.

So there is no need to put & before `[NSHost currentHost]`.

In C language:

```
int *ptr = NULL;
int iVar;
```

You need to assign the address like:

```
ptr = &iVar;
```

If both are pointers:

```
int *ptr  = NULL;
int *iVar = NULL;
```

You can assign the pointer like:

```
ptr = iVar;
```

This is what you are doing in the following code also:

```
NSHost *instance = [NSHost currentHost];
```

**3)**

`NSString *answer = [instance localizedName];` here also the same thing is happening. The `localizedName` returns a pointer of `NSString`

Comment: Hi, so we can set a pointer to a pointer if they hold the same address or they are both NULL?

Comment: @user3090658: Yes. The value of those pointers is NULL. It's just an example.